# EVO 3d ( PG86100 ) - No logs in Logcat via sendlog?

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

Trying to get some logs from a EVO 3D, but each time the logs are sent, they appear to contain no 3rd party app logs. Makes it quite difficult to try and debug an issue which appears only on this one device.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Having the same issue now. Have you ever resolved it?

Comment: Have not been able to fix it. I think I am going to just do the following :
Add preference to allow user to enable/disable logging
Then extend the Log class to enable/disable it, but also allows to write the file to the /sdcard/ 
Add a menu option to email that log to my email address. Not perfect, but should work better than not getting any logs.

Comment: Hey Chrispix, try this, worked for my friend. 1. Close the Log-Cat-View in Eclipse. 2. Restart your Computer and Cellphone. 3. Make Sure your Cellphone allows USB-Debugging. 4. Start Eclipse open LogCatView. 5. Connect your Cellphone ... Now you get Logs! than you choose your application and start it on your cellphone probably it takes a while but than you have your logs back. GL

Comment: Thanks safari, but unfortunately this is for an end user trying to send us logs. They don't have eclipse/sdk/ddms installed.. Oh well.